# Update page content based on search query keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to update page with search results on keyup. This works if `value` does not contain a space. As soon as a space is entered the page will not update. Does the load parameter have to be formatted a certain way?

```
var minlength = 3;

    searchBox.keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            $(".container").load("/media/search/?query=" + value + " " + ".searchresults")
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, space characters (and many others) cannot be used directly in urls. You should use JavaScript build-in function `encodeURIComponent(someString)`. So in your case:

```
    searchBox.keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            $(".container").load("/media/search/?query=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + " " + ".searchresults")
        }
    });
```